# RF signal chain gain

Tags: power, rf, radio, mixer, ham-radio

In conventional electrical signal chain design, we now exactly what is the amplitude of signal in any node, from source to load. In radio frequency circuits which contains antenna. We don't know the exact amplitude (though instead of amplitude they engage power amplitude).

Then, how we should set our required gain in radio frequency circuit stages?

In other word:
Someone asked me to design RF receiver. And I don't know what the power after antenna would be? I am not subjected to that hypothetical transmitter, where the employer having in his mind. And Have you any estimate of that power in mind, as a rule of thumb. For example in horrible conditions the power should be ...dBm and in excellent condition it can be ...dBm?

### Update

I've found my Android phone receiving power called rsrp is about -80 to -90 dBm. Maybe thats my answer.

Comment: why do you think you can't know the amplitude? Use a coupler with known gain and calibrate your power meter or spectrum analyzer to compensate. Or just probe it with a sufficiently high-bandwidth scope, if you're not talking microwave stuff.

Comment: @Hearth for 250MHz or 1Ghz assume, we want to design a receiver and a transmitter for some kind of modulation. In that case how we can know the LNA and amplifiers gain in signal chain?

Comment: @mohammadsdtmnd test them with a network analyzer (VNA).

Comment: If you know the impedance (which you should for a RF design), it's easy to go between power and voltage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RSRP is short for Reference Signal Received Power, used when measuring 4G LTE networks. A cellular phone or another LTE-equipped device would display signal strength in RSRP, measured 0dBm (best signal) to -110dBm (weakest/no signal). An RSRP of -95dBm would be a strong signal whereas -115dBm would be very weak.

Maybe I should follow this for my design on 180MHz.

Answer (score 1):

In low-frequency circuits were often interested in voltages and in many cases can largely ignore current and impedance.  However in RF circuits impedance matching is much more important and it’s more useful to consider power.  Voltage is still there but less used, VSWR measurement being one example.  Gain is typically expressed in terms of power though.

Comment: Sry I think I've asked badly, Maybe the question is, someone asked me to design rf receiver. And I don't know what the power after antenna would be? I am not subjected to that hypothetical transmitter.

Answer (score 1):

> In radio frequency circuits which contains antenna. We don't know the exact amplitude (though instead of amplitude they engage power amplitude).

Are you asking how to measure the power delivered by an antenna? You can measure it with a spectrum analyzer. If your antenna's bandwidth is narrow enough to reject other unwanted signals you can just use an RF power meter.

The amplitude of the signal is easily determined from the power if you know the characteristic impedance of the system.

---

In comments you asked,

> In that case how we can know the LNA and amplifiers gain in signal chain?

These can be measured with a network analyzer. A vector network analyzer (VNA) will measure more accurately, but a scalar network analyzer can be good enough for many applications and is significantly cheaper.

Comment: Sry I think I've asked badly, Maybe the question is, someone asked me to design rf receiver. And I don't know what the power after antenna would be? I am not subjected to that hypothetical transmitter.

Comment: @mohammadsdtmnd because transmission conditions vary, you need to design an rf receiver to work with a wide range of input power levels. You'd need to evaluate the transmitter power and directivity, transmission distance, and receiver antenna design to determine the likely range of power your LNA needs to deal with.

Comment: Have you any estimate of that power in mind, as a rule of thumb. For example in horrible conditions the power should be ...dBm and in excellent condition it can be ...dBm?

Comment: @mohammadsdtmnd, I'm not an RF guy but it depends on how much power your transmitter is licensed for and how much it actually uses, the distance to the receiver, the directivity of the receive antenna and how accurately it's pointed, fading conditions in the channel, ... "Typical" conditions will vary drasmatically between different frequency bands, modulation schemes, ...

Answer (score 0):

Radio transmitters have the antenna as the last stage and engineers can well calculate the strength of the signal which is fed to the antenna. And they do the same for every stage before the antenna.

But the air between the transmitting and receiving antennas and the antennas themselves cause some signal power loss which cannot be exactly predicted - for example there can be some obstacles between and the places of the antennas can vary as people and their equipment move. Most of the tramsmitted energy will never meet any receiving antenna, so it's well possible that a receiver gets only a picowatt from a transmitted watt and that varies drastically when the distance varies.

To compensate the received power variations the receivers have automatic gain control. There's a circuit which adjusts the receiver gain until the signal voltage is good for that part of the radio receiver (=detector) which extracts the original audio, video, data stream or other transferred signal.